# How do say "They use X to mean Y." in Japanese

Tags: grammar, usage, particles, expressions

For example, let's say I want to say:

> The French use "sushi" to mean "nigirizushi".

Is the following Japanese translation correct?

> フランス人は「握り寿司」という意味で「スシ」を使用します。

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In this context, if "sushi" is what the French **say**, I think it would be better to write it in katakana asスシ.  The French don't read or write kanji, so 寿司 is certainly *not* what they **use**.

Answer (score 5):

> The French use "sushi" to mean "nigirizushi".
>   フランス人は「握り寿司」という意味で「スシ」を使用します。

I think it'd be more natural to say it as:

> フランス人は「握り寿司」という意味で「スシ」**と言います**。

But I would probably say it more like:

> フランス人が「スシ」というと、握り寿司のことです。
>   *lit.* When the French say sushi, they mean / it refers to nigirizushi.
>   フランス人が「スシ」というのは、握り寿司のことです。
>   *lit.* What the French call sushi, refers to nigirizushi.
>   フランス人が言う「スシ」とは、握り寿司のことです。 / 握り寿司を指します。
>   *lit.* The sushi that the French say, refers to nigirizushi.

or maybe like this:

> フランスでは、「スシ」というと握り寿司を指します。 / 握り寿司のことを指します。
>   *lit.* In France, when they say sushi, it refers to nigirizushi.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to say this, I would go for something like

> フランス語でスシというと日本語の握り寿司という意味です。

This is a bit different than what you were going to say.  You could perhaps also say something like.

フランス人がスシというときは握り寿司という意味です。

But, I think this is a bit confusing.  For example, does it mean that, when the French say "sushi" while speaking Japanese, they mean "nigiri sushi"?  Probably not, but that's what I chose to go with フランス語.

Comment: 「フランス人**は**スシというとき**に** 」←ここちょっと変えさせてもらってもいいですかね・・

Comment: @ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ Please fix it if it's wrong.  Or explain to me what I've done wrong.  I'm not sure.

Comment: 従属節なので「フランス人**が** 」にして、「～ときに」のほうに topical 「は」を使って、「フランス人**が**スシというとき**は** 」にした方がいいと思います。でも「フランス人がスシというと」のほうが自然な気がします。（ちなみに「フランス人がスシと言ったら」でもいいと思いますが、口語的な感じがします）

Comment: @ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ ありがとうございます。「フランス人がスシと言っ‌​たら』と書こうと思ったんですが。Back to English, why is it that とき feels more natural to be the topic and not フランス人?  I figured that フランス人 was both the subject (and so also the topic) of the subordinate clause and the main clause.  Could you explain?  (Sorry, while my Japanese reading comprehension is pretty decent, I am not so strong in writing responses in Japanese to you.  I guess that's the difference between reading Japanese rather frequently but having not had much opportunity to speak it in for a very long time.)

Comment: @ǝʇɐןoɔoɥƆ Hmmm.  OK, on reflecting about this, I think I get exactly what you're saying and why とき is a more natural sounding topic.

Answer (score 0):

It's not technically wrong, but maybe something like

> フランス語のスシは日本語の握り寿司を意味する

is a little more concise.